# Javafx FXMLLoader.getController() method returns null

Tags: javafx, fxmlloader

When creating the display in my main loop, the loader for an AnchorPane FXML returns null when getController() is called.

```
    //instantiates the FXMLLoader class by calling default constructor
        //creates an FXMLLoader called loader
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        //finds the location of the FXML file to load
        loader.setLocation(mainApp.class.getResource("/wang/garage/view/ItemOverview.fxml"));

        //sets the AnchorPane in the FXML file to itemOverview
        //so that the AnchorPane is set to the display of the app
        AnchorPane itemOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(itemOverview);

        //finds the controller of the itemOverview and
        //sets it to controller variable
        //then provides a reference of mainApp to controller to connect the two
        ItemOverviewController controller = loader.getController();//returns null
        controller.setMainApp(this);
```

I did not specify the controller in the FXML document. Is this necessary if I am using loader.load()? If so, how should I specify the controller in the FXML document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not setting the controller in Java code directly, you need to specify the controller class in the FXML file (else the `FXMLLoader` will have no information as to what kind of object it is supposed to create to use as the controller).

Just add the

```
fx:controller="com.mycompany.myproject.ItemOverViewController
```

attribute to the root element of the FXML file in the usual way.

---

Alternatively, you can set the controller from Java:

```
//instantiates the FXMLLoader class by calling default constructor
//creates an FXMLLoader called loader
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

//finds the location of the FXML file to load
loader.setLocation(mainApp.class.getResource("/wang/garage/view/ItemOverview.fxml"));

// create a controller and set it in the loader:
ItemOverviewController controller = new ItemOverviewController();
loader.setController(controller);

//sets the AnchorPane in the FXML file to itemOverview
//so that the AnchorPane is set to the display of the app
AnchorPane itemOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
rootLayout.setCenter(itemOverview);


//provide a reference of mainApp to controller to connect the two
controller.setMainApp(this);
```